# How do I edit the manifest file of a Microsoft Office 2010 solution in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vsto, ms-office, manifest, administrator

I want to force the addin to run as administrator so I need to edit the manifest to add

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

Comment: That's not possible.  The only shot you have at this is to have your add-in start a *separate* program.  That program can trigger the UAC prompt and acquire the privilege.